# Regexec() not giving the desired result

Tags: c++, c, regex

I need to check whether the month is of the form 01-12.I made a regex and took input to check whether it matches the regex or not.
Code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include<regex.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int a;
 cin>>a;
 cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
 string mon;
 cin>>mon;
 string exp_month = mon;
 string monthRegex = "(0[1-9]|1[0-2])";
 regex_t    preg;
 int        rc;

 if (0 != (rc = regcomp(&preg, monthRegex.c_str(), REG_NOSUB))) {
    cout<<("regcomp() failed, returning nonzero (%d)\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


 if (regexec(&preg,exp_month.c_str(),0,NULL,0)==0)
 {
    cout<<"yess";  
 }
 else
 {
     cout<<"no";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

input 
a =09;
mon =09;
output is "no"

But 09 matches the given regex

Comment: This is an interesting mix of C and C++, why? Also, what is  `year`?

Comment: This isn't a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you can remove lots of code that isn't relevant to your question. It also can't be both C and C++, since they're different languages. Also your indentation could be better.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this
I edited the code now

Comment: Why are you using `regex.h` rather than the C++ `std::regex`? Is using `regex.h` a must here?

Comment: The pipe symbol in regular expression is considered "extended".  Try adding REG_EXTENDED to your regcomp().

Comment: Thanks a lot @brianbeuning
It worked

Comment: Wow, the POSIX/regex.h documentation is awful. That's probably worth posting as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression seems to correct.
Try to use regexp from C++11

```
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
string mon;
cin >> mon;
string monthRegex = "(0[1-9]|1[0-2])";
std::regex rex ( monthRegex );

if ( std::regex_match ( mon, rex ) )
{
    std::cout << "Matched\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not matched\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to BRE POSIX standard (when you do not pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the `regcomp`), the `|` pipe alternation operator, same as `(`/`)` and `{n,m}` characters become "special" only when you escape them. When using ERE POSIX regex flavor (when you pass `REG_EXTENDED` to the `regcomp`), it is just the opposite, *unescaped* `(`, `)`, `|` and `{n,m}` are special.

So, your code can be fixed as

```
string monthRegex = "0[1-9]\\|1[0-2]";
```

Remove `(` and `)` that are treated as literal symbols in BRE, and add escaping symbol before the pipe.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/pquVsR).

Else, use the `REG_EXTENDED` flag and use your own regex:

```
rc = regcomp(&preg, monthRegex.c_str(), REG_NOSUB|REG_EXTENDED)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, it is advisable to use `std::regex` in C++ code, see [arturx64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804958/3832970).